# Tsx compile error in React when casting with as

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-typescript, tsx

The following error shows up whenever "as" is used to cast within .tsx files.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alfXy.png)

> Failed to compile.
>
> src\services\featureService.tsx   Line 10:28:  Parsing error:
> Unexpected token, expected ";"
>
> this.features = {} as Feature[];
>
> ...........................^

This is the package.json

```
{
  "name": "x",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/msal-browser": "^2.10.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.34",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.14",
    "@loadable/component": "^5.14.1",
    "@microsoft/signalr": "^5.0.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@types/loadable__component": "^5.13.3",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "dompurify": "^2.2.6",
    "guid-typescript": "^1.0.9",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.4.3",
    "react-data-table-component": "^6.11.6",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "eslint": "node ./node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js -c .eslintcr.json . --ext .tsx"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/dompurify": "^2.2.1",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7"
  }
}
```

This is the tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

There is also a file called .eslintcr.json

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es6": true,
        "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:react/recommended"
    ],
    "globals": {
        "Atomics": "readonly",
        "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly",
        "JSX": "true"
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": 12,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "indent": [
            "error",
            4
        ],
        "quotes": [
            "error",
            "double"
        ],
        "semi": [
            "error",
            "always"
        ],
        "no-trailing-spaces": [
            "error"
        ],
        "no-multi-spaces": [
            "error",
            { "ignoreEOLComments": true }
        ]
    },
    "parser": "babel-eslint"
}
```